# ADB - svc wifi disable - make it permanent?

Tags: android, shell, wifi, adb, galaxy

I am trying to permanently disable Bluetooth and WiFi on some Galaxy Tab S2's.  They will have material loaded onto them which can not be disseminated on the internet.  Ideally I would like to physically rip the cards out but I have to many to do that - I was thinking about using ADB to somehow disable the services.

Is there a way to do this using ADB?  svc wifi disable works but then a user could just re-enable it in the user interface.  Any thoughts?  I'm not even sure what to search for or where to start.

Comment: If you could do it with ADB, couldn't someone undo it with ADB? Doesn't sound very "permanent" to me. What kind of physical security are you planning on placing on these "not for dissemination" tablets?

Comment: No physical security and yes I guess someone could just re-enable it.  Its more of a policy thing,  I can't give them out to users until Wi-Fi and Bluetooth are disabled based on gov't policy.   If a user re-enables after they signed for it then its a bigger problem.   This is my first android experience and I'm a bit lost.  Can you just delete a file or do you know any 3rd party apps that install something like a admin user?

Comment: if you want brick the wifi/bluetooth part, just delete/rename wifi/bluetooth firmware. but you need `root` permission to do this.

Comment: @Rilwan please elaborate. how do you delete/rename wifi/bluetooth firmware?